# On Button Click constructing a filling values with new Array

Tags: javascript

I have this data as shown, on click of a button, is it possible to construct this `jsonData`  with some different data?

```
var jsonData = [{open:100.01,high:104.06},
        {open:100.02,high:105.06},
        {open:100.03,high:106.06},
        {open:100.04,high:107.06}];

function callMe()
{
}

button onclick= "callMe()";
```

(Later, I will construct this data from Database, right now I am working with only Front End on JavaScript)

Comment: Correct: `button.onclick = callMe;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
var jsonData = [{open:100.01,high:104.06},
        {open:100.02,high:105.06},
        {open:100.03,high:106.06},
        {open:100.04,high:107.06}];

function Clear()
{
    jsonData = new Array();
}

function AddData(open,high)
{
    jsonData.push({'open':open,'high':high});
}

function callMe()
{
    AddData(100.05,108.07);
}

button onclick= "callMe()";
```

Update:

```
var jsonData = [{open:100.01,high:104.06},
        {open:100.02,high:105.06},
        {open:100.03,high:106.06},
        {open:100.04,high:107.06}];

function callMe()
{
    jsonData = [{open:100.01,high:104.06}, 
       {open:100.02,high:105.06}, 
       {open:100.03,high:106.06}, 
       {open:100.04,high:107.06},
       {open:100.05,high:108.06},
       {open:100.06,high:109.06}];
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your reply , on click of that button  i want to construct a different array with some differnt values var jsonData = [{open:200,high:104.06},
        {open:300,high:105.06},
        {open:300,high:106.06},
        {open:444,high:107.06}];

Comment: you can do that, just skip the 'var' or you are creating a local variable.

Comment: @Thorgeir Skip the var to create an implicit global variable? That's hardly good advice.

Comment: well in the code snipped posted in the question the jsonData variable is declared outside of the function and to access it in the callMe function he must skip the var.